# SQL Server Pivot Table with Text Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, dynamic-sql

I have a table named #CODE_LIST, that has a listing of 5 codes and a table named #APPROVAL_LOG, which displays the approval status for a particular code by group.

I would like to display all of the code types and descriptions from #CODE_LIST and pivot the group names into columns from #APPROVAL_LOG. The pivot table should include the group's approval flag for each code type (if available).

Table Name: #CODE_LIST
  [image: Table Name: #CODE_LIST]

Table Name: #APPROVAL_LOG
  [image: Table Name: #APPROVAL_LOG]

Desired Output:
[image: Output Example]

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the output you want so that we can provide an accurate solution?

Comment: I updated the original post to include an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select group_id,
       max(case when code_description = 'BMI' then approval_flag end) as bm_approval,
       . . . 
from approval_log
group by group_id;
```

Just repeat this for each description.

Comment: Is there a way to join both tables and pivot? So the group names appear as column headings and their status are listed below for each code type. I updated the post to include an example of what I mean.

Comment: @Alaskan5 . . . That requires dynamic SQL.